# MYSQL All Columns Being Set/Changed to One Value By Itself?

Tags: php, mysql, database

MySQL- ALL elements in the database table are being accessed, and their values in a column are being set to the same value (5), at EXACTLY the same time by the same visitor/bot periodically.

I have tried banning the IP, but it keeps on happening by different visitors/bots, but doing the SAME thing(as mentioned above). I had even contacted Microsoft when I thought it was their Bot. But it happened again but from a different visitor/Bot.

I use this to insert values onto the table:

```
$write = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stst VALUES('','$pagename','$network','$duration','$stavote','',INET_ATON('$ip'),NOW())");
```

The visitor/Bot inserts the `$pagename`, `$duration( a "60" or "30")` and the `$stavote (a "5")` at the Exact same NOW time.

Of course, I expect individual votes, as I receive. But this "invasion" not only votes on every element in the database, but it also overwrites the other legitimate votes.

What can I adjust to stop this altering of tables values?

Thanks.

Comment: Please about using [prepared statements in PHP](https://php.net/manual/zh/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Mysql_* has been removed in PHP 7. Stop using it now, and start with mysqli_* or PDO, and use prepared statements.

Comment: you need to start using `PHP7` along with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` library with `prepared statements`.2 first you need to check ip already exist or not? if yest then change that row data otherwise insert new value.[BTW ip's are not really correct info to rely on, as they can spoofed easily, as well as proxy servers are considerable too]

Comment: Hello, Will the use of mysqli and Prepared Statements prevent this from happening. I have never heard of prepared statements( I will read up on it). Are the 2 element mentioned better security wise? Please explain if you can. Thank You Again.